# How to get a time FROM the internet, NOT from device in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to know real time (in milliseconds) from the internet not depending on time that is set on a device

`val current = LocalDateTime.now()` so this is NOT what I'm looking for

So if time on my device is 19:30:17.624731634 but the real time in my area is 16:24:52.921262700 the output should be 16:24:52.921262700  (and milliseconds as you see)

Comment: Find an NTP client library and use it.

Comment: Why can't use you use the stock Java time apis, but specify a timezone?

Comment: find an API on the internet that will provide you the time, and make a request to it the way, specified in that API documentation.

Comment: It'll be off by network latency.  I think you're better off with local server time.

Comment: If device has GPS then it is a useful source of time.